# Variance of the number of r.v summed to fill certain capacity

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation

Let us assume that we have a certain capacity T.

We have an infinite number of random variables $X_1,X_2,\dots,$ where each $X_i$ is independent and has a particular pdf $P_i(X)$. And we have that $P[X_i≥0]=1$.

Now we are interested in the number of sucessive variables $X_i$ we can take until the capacity $T$ is used.

That is, we want to find a description for the random variable N such that $\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\leq T$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{N+1} X_i > T$.

I would like to find E[N] and Var[N] but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: By the way, al pdf's $P_i(X)$ are known.

Comment: One could make use of the identities $$[N\geqslant n]=[X_1+\cdots+X_n\leqslant T]$$ and $$E(N)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}P(N\geqslant n),\qquad E(N^2)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}(2n-1)P(N\geqslant n),$$ but there is no guarantee that, in the general case of varying distributions, the result would be simple.

Comment: This has some of the flavor of a Wald sequential test. But there the random variables are IID and the bound T can be a function of n. Is this an abstract exercise, or does it have an applied context, possibly with more information than you have provided?

Answer (score 1):

Without the PDFs themselves, it's hard to proceed very far.  We can observe that

$$
\begin{align}
E(N) & = P(N = 1) + 2P(N = 2) + 3P(N = 3) + \cdots \\
     & = P(N \geq 1) + P(N \geq 2) + P(N \geq 3) \cdots
\end{align}
$$

Let the PDF of $X_i$ be denoted by $f_i(x)$, and let also

$$
g_i = f_1 \ast f_2 \ast \cdots \ast f_i
$$

where $\ast$ represents the convolution operation.  Finally denote by $G_i$ the CDF corresponding to the PDF $g_i$.  Then we can write

$$
E(N) = G_1(T) + G_2(T) + G_3(T) + \cdots
$$

Similarly, we can also write

$$
Var(N) = G_1(T) + 3G_2(T) + 5G_3(T) + \cdots
$$

Perhaps the above will give you enough to get started on whatever you're doing.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. I just wonder how you get that expected value dependent on the CDF's ($G_i$).

Comment: I think that the expected value should be something like $\mathbb{E}(N)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty iG_i(T)\left(1-G_{i+1}(T)\right)$